# compiling problems with latex and embedded python code

Tags: python, latex, pdflatex

I'm using Ubuntu server with Python 2.7 and LaTeX and I try try to compile this LaTeX code with the shell command: pdflatex test.tex

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{python}

\begin{document}

     \begin{python}
     print "Hello World"
     \end{python}

\end{document}
```

It's pretty simple, because it's my first attempt with both together but I get this error message:

```
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/python/python.sty

Package: python 2007/06/07 v0.21 Python in LaTeX
\@out=\write3
\@module=\write4
) (./test.aux)

! I can't write on file `test.aux'.

\document ...ate \openout \@mainaux \jobname .aux          
\immediate \write \@mainau...
l.5 \begin{document}                   

(Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit; default file extension is `.tex')
Please type another output file name: 
! Emergency stop.
\document ...ate \openout \@mainaux \jobname .aux
```

Is it maybe a permission problem or anything else?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any experience with the LaTeX package in question, but from what I can tell it will try to execute the python snippet and include the output.  Try removing the leading whitespace from the python segment:

```
\begin{python}
print "Hello World!"
\end{python}
```

instead of:

```
     \begin{python}
     print "Hello World!"
     \end{python}
```

The extraneous leading whitespace will cause the python interpreter to throw an `IndentationError` which is probably what is confusing python.sty.  A cursory look at [python.sty](http://goodmami.org/files/python.sty) leads me to believe that it is going to do what the following shell commands would do:

```
prompt$ echo '     print "Hello World!"' > test.py
prompt$ cat test.py | python > test.py.out 2> test.py.err
```

Then it will do an verbatim include of *test.py.out* which will be empty.  The standard error output will contain something like:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
  print "Hello World!"
  ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

There is a mention in the sty file that he shouldn't be ignoring the standard error output.  I have a feeling that if the `python` interpreter exits unsuccessfully, then the output is never generated by LaTeX but I could be wrong.

Comment: Thanks you very much. Now I understand the process much better and it works how you describe it. If I manually create the file test.py.out and I write some some text inside, it works.
But this isn't the solution because the file and the content has to be created automatically.

Comment: Did you try removing the leading whitespace in the LaTeX document?  That is probably the source if the issue.

Comment: I found the problem. The problem wasn't the whitespace. I read the python.sty again. There is written "NOTE: shell-escape needs to be activated for this work. [...] adding/changing 'shell_escape = t' in your texmf.cnf". I changed it and voila it works. Thank you for talking about and the inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

Error messages are there for your benefit!

```
! I can't write on file `test.aux'.
```

means that LaTex is trying to write something to the file 'test.aux', but can't. The most likely reason is that the file is locked because you have it open in something else.

You should be able to check this by attempting to delete the file. Once you unlock it you should be fine; worst-case, reboot.

Comment: I've rebooted the system and and if try to delete the file ubuntu tells me it is a write-protected regular file.
I changed the permissions with chmod 777 for the files: test.aux, test.log, test.py and latex.py. Now the error message is: I can't find file test.py.out. But there is no such a file.